# How do I change $cart_total to an actual number?

Tags: php, arrays, shopping-cart, cart

I am integrating mercadopago (Brasil's version of paypal) into my existing shopping cart that currently checks out and person makes bank deposit.

All seems well except the unit_price is a fixed number.

```
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
       array(
           "title" => "Shirt",
           "quantity" => 1,
           "currency_id" => "BRL",
           "unit_price" => "10.00"
       )
    )
);
```

I have tried saying `"unit_price" => "$cart_total"` but it returned an error saying `unit_price` must be a number. is there any way around this?

I have miraculously developed my own website and have a .php cart but I am not entirely knowledgeable in this area!!!! Thank you so much! Sorry about the easy question, I couldn't find the answer because I don't know how to properly word it. I tried looking for "converting php string to integer" but that returned results that did not apply...

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use quotes when setting `unit_price`. As for the `quantity` number, instead of:

```
"unit_price" => "10.00"
```

do:

```
"unit_price" => 10.00
```

Read more about PHP types: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
"unit_price" => (float)$cart_total,
```